# WPF Window that only shows in TaskBar

Tags: wpf, taskbar, splash-screen

I'm not sure if what I want to do is appropriate, so I'll explain a little.

We've got a large application that takes a while to load.  So we have a splash screen.
The Splash screen causes excessive load time on Remote Desktop (terminal server).
So to alleviate this, we want to hide the splash screen when loading on RDP.
But we still need to at least show the user that the application is loading.

So, I was thinking perhaps just show something in the Taskbar (not the system tray), as it will disappear once the application is fully loaded (and be replaced by the main form's Task icon).
However any WPF solution I've looked at, requires a visible form/window to go with the Taskbar status.

Is there any way of showing something in the Taskbar without showing a WPF window?

Or is there another way of showing application load status without something on the screen?

Comment: Are you using the `SplashScreen` class? Can you explain the excessive load time? Is it perhaps due to animations in your splash screen? Have you seen this? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/02/27/optimizing-visual-studio-2010-and-wpf-applications-for-remote-desktop.aspx

Comment: The excessive load time seems to be tied to a paint issue with our application (WinForms).  Because it has a high number of controls, paint time is higher.  Additionaly because it sits on top of another framework for handling Hwnds.
But the performance issue I found, was when the splash screen was still visible, the paint time of the application exceeded normal expectations (>1min).  It wasn't until the splash screen was hidden, that the application reduced to only a 1~3 seconds to paint.  I can only guess there is some screen buffer issue with RDP between the two windows.

Comment: No, I hadn't realised there was SplsahScreen class.  Our splashscreen isn't animated.  Just dynamic (updating text for load status), with a WPF Effect and a large PNG.  Removing the Effect didn't improve load time on RDP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had same problem.

On remote desktop, we did following steps...

1. We configured the Splash window to not allow resizing and have only Minimize and Close button.
2. We removed WindowStyle=None setting so that title bar of the Splash window appeared
3. We made the Splash window's width and height zero. This way all you see on screen is a small blue rectangle of the title bar with Text "Loading... Please Wait ..." and minimize and Close button.
4. We used Window's kernel calls to disable title bar's Close button too. This way user was not able to cancel the Splash window.
5. So all a user could do is to minimize or restore from taskbar.

When restored, all he sees is a title bar's blue rectangle with "Loading..." text. This way the window also claimed its place on the task bar but hid its splash animation and user is also aware that the splash screen is loading. For this you can also update the Title bar's text by appending more fullstops ...

Loading. Please Wait..

Loading. Please Wait...

Loading. Please Wait....

Loading. Please Wait..

Comment: Well, I can't mark both as answer, but both AngelWPF and Paul's responses were relevant.
With our already existing Splash Window, there is now an alternate ShowSplash() method.
* Removed the ShowInTaskbar="False"
* Set the Size to 0, 0
* Set the child control Size to 0,0.
* Added Title.
* Added an Icon.
Other settings had to remain.
We have looked at the performance issue, but this is tied into a lot of legacy code that was translated from an older application, which is now on a framework to emulate much of the old base.

Answer (score 0):

I do think you need to look into the root cause of your issue. Possibly looking at threading and parallelism.

However, a simple solution to what you are asking would be to just create a hidden window. One that is transparent, no borders or anything. It could even bet set to a size of 0, 0. That way you would be able to get the taskbar item that you require.